# Не приходят заголовки при подключении Google oauth2 (express, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, google-oauth2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Server:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

let googleOptions = {
  clientID: ENV.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: ENV.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "/user/auth/google/callback"
};
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(googleOptions,
  function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // make the code asynchronous
    console.log("googleStrategy");
    process.nextTick(async () => {
      console.log(profile);
    });
  }
));

app.get('/auth/*/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { 
    failureRedirect: '/auth' }),
    function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Ответ должен прийти от Google или мне его надо где-то вернуть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что я отправлял запрос посредством XMLHttpRequest

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = withCredentials;
xhr.open('GET', http://site.com/auth/google);
xhr.send();
```

А надо было просто перейти по ссылке `http://site.com/auth/google`